# What's the difference between `scoped` and `module` in vuejs components?

Tags: vuejs2

I understand that with 'scoped' i can isolate css stylings to a component, so What's the difference between `scoped` and `module` in vuejs components? When should I use module over scoped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/features/css-modules.html):

> CSS Modules as an alternative for simulated scoped CSS

So, it's an alternative - It's also worth noting that `scoped` on a parent component means child components can't see the CSS but with `module` you can access `this.$parent.$style.red` to gain access to the styling.

It does however have the added advantage that you can then access your CSS from within your code:

```
<style module>
  .red {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<script>
  export default {
    created () {
      console.log(this.$style.red)
    }
  }
</script>
```